# Warning: Function created with compilation error in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TOTALSALARY
RETURN NUMBER
IS 
TOTAL_SAL  NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  SELECT NVL(SUM(SALARY),0) INTO TOTAL_SAL FROM EMPLOYEE
  RETURN TOTAL_SAL
END TOTALSALARY;
/
```

Here is the ques

Write a PL/SQL function that should return the total salary of all the employees.

Functional Requirement:

Function Name: TOTALSALARY

EMPLOYEE:

```
Column name Data type   Constraints
EMP_ID  NUMBER(5)   PK
FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(25)    NOT NULL
LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(25)     
DEPT    VARCHAR2(25)
SALARY                  NUMBER
```

Comment: In pl/sql all statements need to end with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the semicolon (;) in the end of SELECT and RETURN statements.
Try like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TOTALSALARY
RETURN NUMBER
IS 
TOTAL_SAL  NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  SELECT NVL(SUM(SALARY),0) INTO TOTAL_SAL FROM EMPLOYEE;
  RETURN TOTAL_SAL;
END TOTALSALARY;
/
```

Comment: This will compile... but error out if table employee has > 1 row...